# Как скрыть вкладку QTabWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qtabwidget, clear

Подскажите, как скрыть вкладку. Не помогает ни `hide()`, ни `setVisible()`

Только удалить можно через `deleteLater()`, но это мне не подходит.

Подскажите другие способы решения проблемы. Заранее спасибо.

Пример удаления:

```
Self.ui.tab_7.deleteLater()
```

Comment: добавьте код в вопрос

Comment: сохранить копию и позицию, удалить, в нужный момент вставить?

Comment: если в c++ то imho надо сохранить указатель с помощью `QWidget *widget(int index) const`, а затем удалить с помощью `void QTabWidget::removeTab(int index)`

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.tab_widget = QTabWidget()

        self._dictTabs = [
            ['Tab 1', QPushButton('Tab 1')],
            ['Tab 2', QPushButton('Tab 2')],
            ['Tab 3', QPushButton('Tab 3')],
        ]

        for k, v in self._dictTabs: #.items():
            self.tab_widget.addTab(v, k)

        self.comboBox = QComboBox()
        self.comboBox.setFixedHeight(50)
        self.comboBox.addItems(['Выберите вкладку, кот. не показывать\n(показать все вкладки)', 
                                'Tab 1', 'Tab 2', 'Tab 3'])
        self.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.onCurrentIndexChanged)

        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.comboBox)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.tab_widget)
        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)

    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def onCurrentIndexChanged(self, index):
        self.tab_widget.hide()
        self.tab_widget = QTabWidget() 
        if index == 0:
            for k, v in self._dictTabs: 
                self.tab_widget.addTab(v, k) 
        else:
            for k, v in self._dictTabs:                   
                if k != f'Tab {index}' and index:
                    self.tab_widget.addTab(v, k)
        self.tab_widget.show()
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.tab_widget)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    app.setFont(QFont("Times", 12, QFont.Bold))
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.resize(300, 200)
    mw.show()
    app.exec()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

По совету компетентных товарищей @gil9red

> Мб не пересоздавать объект QTabWidget, а очищать его вкладки (doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#clear) и после заново заполнять?

---

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.tab_widget = QTabWidget()

        self._dictTabs = [
            ['Tab 1', QPushButton('Tab 1')],
            ['Tab 2', QPushButton('Tab 2')],
            ['Tab 3', QPushButton('Tab 3')],
        ]

        for k, v in self._dictTabs: #.items():
            self.tab_widget.addTab(v, k)

        self.comboBox = QComboBox()
        self.comboBox.setFixedHeight(50)
        self.comboBox.addItems(['Выберите вкладку, кот. не показывать\n(показать все вкладки)', 
                                'Tab 1', 'Tab 2', 'Tab 3'])
        self.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.onCurrentIndexChanged)

        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.comboBox)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.tab_widget)
        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)

    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def onCurrentIndexChanged(self, index):
        self.tab_widget.clear()                                    # +++
#        self.tab_widget.hide()                                    # ---
#        self.tab_widget = QTabWidget()                            # ---
        if index == 0:
            for k, v in self._dictTabs: 
                self.tab_widget.addTab(v, k) 
        else:
            for k, v in self._dictTabs:                   
                if k != f'Tab {index}' and index:
                    self.tab_widget.addTab(v, k)
#        self.tab_widget.show()                                    # ---   
#        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.tab_widget)               # ---


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    app.setFont(QFont("Times", 12, QFont.Bold))
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.resize(300, 200)
    mw.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: Мб не пересоздавать объект `QTabWidget`, а очищать его вкладки (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#clear) и после заново заполнять?

Comment: @gil9red спасибо за совет, так будет правильнее.

Comment: Тогда имеет смысл убрать `self.tab_widget.hide()`, `self.tab_widget.show()` и `self.main_layout.addWidget(self.tab_widget)` :)

Comment: @gil9red да, спасибо .

Answer (score 1):

Действительно, в API виджета нет такого метода, хотя он был бы полезным.

Поиск решения [привел на форум](https://forum.qt.io/topic/23803/solved-hiding-tab-from-qtabwidget-made-in-qtcreator/3) и там был предложен трюк с `QSS`:

> There's no built in method like setTabVisible(false) unfortunately.
>   The workaround I often use is applying this stylesheet: @
>   QTabWidget::tab:disabled { width: 0; height: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0;
>   border: none; } @ and then using setTabEnabled(false). Of course if
>   you also need disabled (grayed out) tabs this method won't work.

Суть в том, что при состояние `disabled` прятать вкладку убрав ей размеры, отступы и границы. В ответе, кст, есть небольшая опечатка не `QTabWidget::tab:disabled`, а `QTabBar::tab:disabled`

[Реализация](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/3339b2caec35762bdcb74bc7857d80bc54bf3486/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/show_hide_tabs__QTabWidget.py#L19):

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QTabWidget, QPushButton


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.tab_widget = QTabWidget()
        self.tab_widget.tabBar().setStyleSheet("""
            ::tab:disabled { width: 0; height: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: none; }
        """)

        self.tab_widget.addTab(QPushButton('Tab 1'), 'Tab 1')
        self.tab_widget.addTab(QPushButton('Tab 2'), 'Tab 2')
        self.tab_widget.addTab(QPushButton('Tab 3'), 'Tab 3')

        self.button = QPushButton('Show/Hide tab #2')
        self.button.setCheckable(True)
        self.button.setChecked(True)
        self.button.clicked.connect(lambda checked: self.tab_widget.setTabEnabled(1, checked))

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(self.button)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.tab_widget)

        self.setLayout(main_layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

Указываем стиль конкретно для `tabBar()` того виджета `self.tab_widget`: `self.tab_widget.tabBar().setStyleSheet`

Спрятали вторую вкладку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Грех не присоединиться к такой честной компании с третьим вариантом (немного инициализации взял у S.Nick).

Ключевой момент - использование функции `QTabWidget.removeTab(index)`:

```
class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.tab_widget = QTabWidget()
        # словарь скрытых табов
        self.hidden_tabs = {}

        self._dictTabs = [
            ['Tab 1', QPushButton('Tab 1')],
            ['Tab 2', QPushButton('Tab 2')],
            ['Tab 3', QPushButton('Tab 3')],
        ]

        for title, widget in self._dictTabs:
            self.tab_widget.addTab(widget, title)
            # инициализируем словарь ключами-заголовками табов
            # можно этого и не делать, но для наглядности
            self.hidden_tabs[title] = None

        # кнопка прятания текущего таба
        self.button_hide_tab = QPushButton('Скрыть текущий таб')
        self.button_hide_tab.clicked.connect(self.__slot_hide_current_tab)
        # кнопка показа всех ранее вкрытых табов
        # можно, конечно, показывать табы по какому-либо условию
        self.button_show_hidden_tabs = QPushButton('Показать все скрытые табы')
        self.button_show_hidden_tabs .clicked.connect(self.__slot_show_tab)


    def __slot_hide_current_tab(self): 
        index = self.tab_widget.currentIndex()
        if index == -1:
            return
        # сохраняем текущий таб в список скрытых
        self.hidden_tabs[title] = self.tab_widget.currentWidget()

        # скрываем таб из tab_widget
        self.tab_widget.removeTab(index)

    def __slot_show_tab(self): 
        # бежим по скрытышам
        for title, widget in self._hidden_tabs:
            # если скрытыш есть, то показываем его, добавляя в конец
            if widget:
                self.tab_widget.addTab(widget, title)
```